# NSArray blank - Passing between UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, arrays, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, nsarray

I have an iOS application which needs to pass an NSArray between two ViewControllers. However when the NSArray gets passed its blank.... (in the view that it gets passed to).

Here is my code:

**VIEW ONE - header file**

```
// Detail view property - pass data on.
@property (nonatomic, retain) DetailView *data_pass;
```

**VIEW ONE - implementation file**

```
@synthesize data_pass;

NSArray *image_iphone = [[res objectForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"pictures"];

UIStoryboard *newStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:view_name bundle:nil];
DetailView *firstvc = [newStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
self.data_pass = firstvc;
data_pass.input_image = image_iphone[indexPath.row];
[self presentViewController:firstvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**VIEW TWO - header file**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *input_image;
```

**VIEW TWO - implementation file**

```
@synthesize input_image;

NSLog(@"VIEW DID APPEAR LOG: %@\n\n", input_image);
```

In the first view controller "VIEW ONE" I have checked the NSArray that I am passing and it is NOT blank at all...

Here is the output I get in the second view controller "VIEW TWO":

```
VIEW DID APPEAR LOG: (
)
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have creates NSArray in view TWO and you passes just a single object. this may be reason for the blank Log. Try for Passing whole arry not indexpath.row.....

Comment: image_iphone[indexPath.row]; are you sure this is returning you an array? have you debugged it?

Comment: Try `self.data_pass.input_image = image_iphone[indexPath.row];`.  Oddly, if the only `data_pass` in your code is the property, I'm surprised your version compiles.

Comment: Try self.data_pass.input_image=[NSArray aloc]init]; and  self.data_pass.input_image = image_iphone[indexPath.row];

Comment: My guess is that you create two copies of VIEW ONE, set the array data in the first, but then pass the array from the second to VIEW TWO.  But it's hard to tell for sure since you're not showing us real code.

Comment: Show u sthe log for `image_iphone[indexPath.row];`

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I have put an answer below, there were two main issues but one of them was indeed the indexPath.row issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what was wrong in the end. But thank you to all the people who left comments, they helped a lot!!

The issue was with two things:

1) As @RamaniAshish said - I was passing indexPath.row and NOT the whole NSArray. For some reason this means that the contents of the array doesn't get passed.

2) The second issue was with one of my if statements which was checking for the wrong thing and so the correct array that was being passed in was not being checked in the second view controller.

Thanks for all you help fellow devs :)